# singularity / ubuntu : how to use the host authentical agent

Tags: ubuntu, ssh-keys, singularity-container

A singularity image created from ubuntu 18.04 (or newer) has a run script which, among other things, git clone some repositories using ssh.

Ideally, I would like that: when the image is executed, the (already activated) ssh key of the host is used for the (git ssh clone) authentication.

So things could be run like:

```
ssh-add ~/.ssh/my_key # and possibly typing password
./myimage.sif
```

Would this be possible ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer: yes

- `SINGULARITY_BIND=$SSH_AUTH_SOCK ./myimage.sif`
- `singularity run -B $SSH_AUTH_SOCK myimage.sif`

---

Long answer: yes, as long as the right directories and environment variables passed to the image.

You need:

1. `git`/`ssh` installed in the singularity image (may or may not be in a default docker image)
2. your `$HOME` directory mounted in. This is default, but may need to do it manually (`-H /home/my_user`) depending on configuration
3. ssh-agent environment variable `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` exported. By default your host environment is passed into the container, but this can be disabled with `-e | --cleanenv`

   - See also: [docs on environment variables](https://sylabs.io/guides/3.7/user-guide/environment_and_metadata.html#environment-overview)
4. the path set in `$SSH_AUTH_SOCK` mounted in. This is why we're using `SINGULARITY_BIND` or `-B $SSH_AUTH_SOCK`

   - See also: [docs on bind paths and mounts](https://sylabs.io/guides/3.7/user-guide/bind_paths_and_mounts.html)

An easy way to test if your keys are being accessed correctly:

```
$ singularity exec -B $SSH_AUTH_SOCK myimage.sif ssh -T git@github.com
Hi tsnowlan! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.
```